# Should I put SPF checks before or after RBL checks in Postfix SMTP server?

Tags: postfix, configuration, email-server, spf, blacklist

I am setting up a Postfix SMTP server (pre v2.10) and was thinking to put the smtpd_recipient_restrictions as follows.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_rbl_client sub.domain.tld,
    reject_rhsbl_reverse_client sub.domain.tld,
    reject_rhsbl_helo sub.domain.tld,
    reject_rhsbl_sender sub.domain.tld,
    check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
```

Would it work, and might it be an even better idea, to put the SPF checks before the RBL and RHSBL checks, so as to limit (if the SPF check might block something before reaching the RBL and RHSBL checks) the number of queries to the RBL and RHSBL lists/services?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

RBL checks happen based on the incoming IP of the connection and can dispatch a 'bad' connection very quickly.  SPF checks must wait for the SMTP conversation to begin and are therefore require more resources.  In a high-volume situation, doing RBL first is "cheaper"

Comment: Thanks for the information. I thought that everything in the Postfix smtpd_..._restrictions happened before the message was accepted, and that SPF and RBL checks both involve checking against remote records, and so would use similar resources. So, I thought it might minimize queries to the RBL and RHSBL lists/services if the SPF checks might block something first. Does using the SPF check as a check_policy_service not check before the "SMTP conversation [is begun]"?

Comment: It can't. SPF is based on the purported MAIL FROM: value, which at the very least comes after an HELO/EHLO handshake and often will come after TLS connection establishment as well.

RBL lookups are cheap, network and processor-wise, by comparison, though make sure you put a timeout on the lookups in case of slow RBLs or connectivity issues so as not to exhaust your connections.  

Again, if it's not a very high-volume situation it probably won't matter.

Comment: Thanks again. I have a number of other restrictions set at the client, helo, and sender levels. I have left the RBL checks until near the end in the recipient restrictions so that they will not even be needed unless the earlier restrictions have not caught something. I guess the way that I was interpreting your comment about the "SMTP conversation [beginning]" was meaning that a message had been accepted -- but I see now what you mean. I agree, it might not matter too much the order of RBL and SPF on a small setup, but did wonder about it in the potential setup shown above.